# About adding new localizable(language) in iTunes Connect for app release

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

If I add new localizable(language) for my existing app in iTune Connect:

[image]

I also added localized meta data e.g. Descrption etc.

**My questions:**

**1.** After app released out, is the localized meta data showing to user based on phone language setting or based on the region the phone is located?

**2.** My app hide one feature for one country, if I write different Description metadata for different localizable information, will my app being rejected by App during review process?